# Using an for to repeat the number o rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

Hy. im trying to use an for to repeat the number of rows.

```
valorrepetir = []

for index, row in tabela.iterrows():
    print(int(row['Quantidade Entrada']))
    valorrepetir.append(int(row['Quantidade Entrada']))

for i in valorrepetir:
   print(i)
   tabela_new = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(tabela.values, i, axis=0))
```

I use this code but instead of replicating the lines based on a value that is stock in each line it repeats all the lines based on the last stock number of the last line

I think the problem is in the second for when a create a new dataframe but i dont know how to do it.

Can anyone help?!!

Comment: 1) From this `%sql` I'm assuming you are using `ipython` is that correct? If so add that information to your question. 2) Per here [Type adaption](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#adaptation-of-python-values-to-sql-types) `psycopg` has no idea what to do with a `numpy` type/object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create the new data frame outside the loop that iterates over `valorrepetir`, and then use the repeat() function to repeat each row of the original data frame based on the value in `valorrepetir`.

```
tabela = pd.DataFrame({'Quantidade Entrada': [2, 3, 4], 'Valor': [10, 20, 30]})

valorrepetir = tabela['Quantidade Entrada'].tolist()

tabela_new = tabela.loc[np.repeat(tabela.index.values, valorrepetir)]

print(tabela_new)
```